# Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2-2q^2=1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

> Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2-2q^2=1.$

My idea so far was to observe that since $2q^2$ is even, then $q^2$ must be odd or even. If $q^2$ is even, then $q$ is even and the only even prime is $2.$ Thus one pair of primes $(p,q)=(3,2).$

But, if $q^2$ is odd, then $q$ is also odd and $q=2d+1$ for some integer $d.$ Then,

$p^2-2q^2=1$ turns into $p^2=4(2d^2+2d)+3.$

From here I do not know how to proceed.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Since $p^2-2q^2=1$, $p$ must be odd. Furthermore, $q$ must be even; if $q$ were odd, then $p^2-2q^2$ would be $3$ mod $4$. Thus, $q=2$ and then $p=3$.

Comment: Very elegant solution. +$1$

Comment: Most elegant solution. *+5*

Answer (score 8):

From your last expression we have $$\tag1(p+1)(p-1)=2\cdot[\;2(2d^2+2d)+1\;].$$ 
 If $p=2$ then you get from the original expression that $2q^2=3,$ which is impossible. Therefore $p>2$ and hence $p$ is odd. Then $p-1$ and $p+1$ are both even, which implies that their product $(p+1)(p-1)$ is divisible by $4$ which is clearly false by $(1).$ Therefore $q$ must be even and thus it must be equal $2,$ which implies that $p=3.$

**Another approach**: Since $p^2-2q^2=1$ then $(p+1)(p-1)=2q^2$ and the Unique Factorization Theorem implies that either $p+1=q^2\;\wedge\;p-1=2$ or $p+1=2q\;\wedge\;p-1=q$ but in either case $p=3$ and $q=2.$

Comment: The way you have written your last statement seems a bit unusual. I read it as though you are saying $xy=p\cdot q^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers implies $p=x$ and $y=q^2$, which is not true.

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Comment: What you've said in your post isn't wrong, it's just how it reads to me. I thought I'd let you know in case it was an error you agreed with and didn't notice beforehand

Answer (score 2):

$p^2-2q^2\equiv p^2+q^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

But $a^2\equiv \{0,1\}\pmod{3}$ for all $a\in\Bbb Z$, so exactly one of $p,q$ is equal to $3$.

$q=3$ gives $p^2=19$, impossible. $p=3$ gives $(p,q)=(3,2)$.

Comment: Far and away the most accessible answer given. +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT ON THE SEARCH OF ALL SOLUTIONS

As an elementary consequence of Dirichlet's theorem of units on number fields, we have for the quadratic cases the general solution of the equation of Pell-Fermat $x^2-dy^2=\pm1$ which concerns the units (a.e. elements of norm equal to $\pm1$) of the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$.

The field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ has as fundamental unit  of its ring of integers 
$\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ the number $1+\sqrt 2$ so it is known that all the integer solutions of the equation $$x^2-2y^2=1$$ are given by $$a_{2n}+b_{2n}\sqrt 2=(1+\sqrt 2)^{2n}$$
Here we are interested in all the $(a_{2n},b_{2n})$  being both primes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily checks for solutions in {2,3,5}.

For prime p $\geq$ 6, $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod6$ $ \Rightarrow p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod6$ .Therefore, $ p^2 - 2q^2 \equiv 1 -2 \equiv -1 \not\equiv  1\pmod6$

Hence, no solutions other than (3,2) exists.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach (just for exercising).

We use the knowledge that $1=3^2-2 \cdot 2^2$ and rewrite the initial formula as
$$ p^2 - 2q^2 = 3^2-2 \cdot 2^2 \tag 1$$
and then
$$ p^2 - 3^2 = 2(q^2-2^2) \tag 2$$
Factoring gives
$$(p-3)(p+3) = 2(q-2)(q+2) \tag 3$$

Now the lhs must be even (because the rhs is), thus $p$ must be odd (additionally: an odd prime by problem statement), and the lhs is divisible by at least $2^3=8$.

So the parentheses in the rhs must be even, and thus $q$ must be even and thus $q=2$ as the only even prime.

Then the rhs is zero, thus the lhs must be zero, thus $p=3$ and $(p,q)=(3,2)$ is the only solution.